# A go code program failed to run in the background

Tags: go

Go code running in the background

I am a beginner of the go language.
I wrote a small program that made a keyboard sound.
After `go build main.go`, you can hear the sound of the button in the current shell.
But when running `./main` in the background or when re-opening a new shell will not hear the button sound.
This is what I need help with.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/eiannone/keyboard"
    "github.com/faiface/beep"
    "github.com/faiface/beep/speaker"
    "github.com/faiface/beep/wav"
    "os"
    "time"
    "log"
    "path/filepath"

)

func main(){

    env:= os.Getenv("HOME")
    fmt.Println(env)

    err := keyboard.Open()
    if err != nil {

        panic(err)
    }
    defer keyboard.Close()
    for {
        char, key, err := keyboard.GetKey()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }else if (key == keyboard.KeyEsc){
            break
        }

        n := int(char)
        path := "./wav/*.wav"
        fpath,_ := filepath.Glob(path)
        name := fpath[n]

        f, err := os.Open(name)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        streamer, format, err := wav.Decode(f)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer streamer.Close()

        speaker.Init(format.SampleRate, format.SampleRate.N(time.Second/10))

        done := make(chan bool)
        speaker.Play(beep.Seq(streamer, beep.Callback(func() {
            done <- true
        })))

        <-done

    }

}
```

I want it to run in the background. I can hear the corresponding sound after pressing the keyboard.

Comment: That's up to the OS to do - or prevent. You will need to check your OS's API for some functionality that allows intercepting these events when the application is not in focus.

Answer (score 0):

If the program is running in the background it will not get any input from the keyboard.

Also since `n` depends on user input it would be easy for it to exceed the number of sound files and you would get an index out of bounds error at run-time.  You should do something like this:

```
    if fpath, _ := filepath.Glob("./wav/*.wav"); len(fpath) > 0 {
        n := int(char)%len(fpath)
           name := fpath[n]
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks Reply
Yes, the program can't run in the background. This is also the problem I want to solve.
I don’t know why, I don’t know how to solve it.